# Create own log in system or use something else like devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am starting to create a website and I want to set up a simple log in. I will be using ruby on rails and I am wondering if I should create my own log in or use something like devise? I also want to integrate facebook log in so that if a user authorizes it, then the name and email fields will auto-populate with the data I get from facebook. They will then just have to enter a password to complete the log in.

Comment: Devise and OmniAuth integrate nicely if you need Facebook support. There's a RailsCast which demonstrates this. [Doing authentication correctly is hard, and you shouldn't reinvent it.](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2011/05/26/38672/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple rule of thumb I use is this. Try the plugin, test it against your use cases. If it works for you, use it. Why reinvent the wheel when your time could be better spent writing new code. If you find it doesn't do what you need, see if you can extend it, remember it's open source. Then, if you cannot extend it and you still need more functionality, look into creating your own.

Authentication is pretty standard fare at this point, you probably won't have something so complex that devise can't handle it.

Comment: As Paul alludes to below, there are a lot of best practices that existing libraries take care of for you... such as proper hashing and salting... and much more. Rolling your own means you either know all of the security practices, or you will make an insecure app.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use devise; there's a ton of best practices already implemented for you, especially if you're later looking to do FB auth or OAuth.